# Debug a Spring app by mvn jetty:run and debug angular frontend simultaneously in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: angularjs, spring, maven, debugging, jetty

Is it possible to debug a Spring application running on jetty and the front-end angular part at the same time in IntelliJ Idea?

The breakpoints in the backend work great, but the front-end ones are ignored.

Comment: You installed the Intellij Browser extension right?

Comment: @dav1d  yes, i have two parralel debug sessions running in intellij: one for mvn and one for javascript debug. Chrome displays that idea is listening, but it doesn't react to breakpoints and there is not info about scripts in idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done in this way with IntelliJ Idea:

**For backend (pretty obvious)**

Create a Maven run profile and pass in these arguments: jetty:run.

Then debug this run configuration. This will enable you to 'listen' to the backend of your application.

**For frontend:**

Create a JavaScript Debug run profile and set it up as follows: 
URL: http://localhost:9070/ (this is where my jetty server and my application was running).

Then you have to set the REMOTE URL of the directory where you AngularJS app is (in my case it was /app) to: http://localhost:9070/

And all that's left is to run as debug this configuration and that will make debugging the front end possible also.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's posible.
You need to install this Chrome Extension: 
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jetbrains-ide-support/hmhgeddbohgjknpmjagkdomcpobmllji?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon

To debug the angular project, you create a new debug configuration:

In IntelliJ Idea go to Run -> Edit configurations.
Click the + button (Add New Configuration) and select the JavaScript Debug.
Change the URL with your application local development url, usually http://localhost:4200/

Save the configuration, execute `ng serve` and run the configuration in debug mode.

You get the breakpoints working in server and client!!!